# Any Cycle Playing Option for QuickTime for videos

Tags: video, quicktime

I would like to play a video in cycle i.e. to start again after end. 
How can you do this? 
I did not find any setting in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be simple using the QuickTime menu.

Go to View and select loop.

or use `alt+cmd+l`